# Android NDK Unsatisfied link error of .so file of another AAR project

Tags: android, android-ndk, .so

I have one  Android AAR project  which contains .so file in jnilibs folder. when i try to include this aar file in other android project(non-ndk)  it works fine and system.loadlibrary("Mysample.so") returns successfully.

But when i try to include the same aar in **android-ndk** project, system.loadlibrary("Mysample.so") throws unsatisfiedlinking error.

I wonder why its just doesnot work in android ndk project?

Any help would be appreciated.